# Function preg_match() is not returning any value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match a pattern from a string and parse them further... But it's not returning any value...

Actually, I'm using that to fetch the videos by looking after the header information.

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $video_id;
$this->req =& new HTTP_Request($url);
$response = $this->req->sendRequest();
$rescode  = $this->req->getResponseCode();

echo "++response code++$rescode";
echo "***$response***";

if (PEAR::isError($response)) {
    echo "<b>Please check whether the video added or not </b>";
} 
else {
    $page = $this->req->getResponseBody();
    //echo "=====$page====";

    preg_match('/"videoplayback": "(.*?)"/', $page, $match);

    $var_id = $match[1];
    echo "+++$var_id+++;
}
```

All are working fine if I replace the preg_match call with the below code, but that’s not what I need..

```
preg_match('/"video_id": "(.*?)"/', $page, $match);
```

The string which I'm trying to match is:

> http://v17.lscache6.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Calgorithm%2Cburst%2Cfactor%2Coc%3AU0dYR1RMVl9FSkNNOF9MRlpB&fexp=906320&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=0&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1292418000&key=yt1&signature=32DD3C5BF016489B43D15493F68ACCDE2AA720B5.95F66ACBE6FDFBC60978A14075A28020E083E8A8&factor=1.25&id=39743a9fde40b0dd&

How can I fix this?

Comment: @kvihayhari: have you tried to dump the content of page, just like if you didn't hit a 404 or some other page ...

Comment: are you trying to extract `some_string` from `"videoplayback": "some_string"` ? if so, string you provided doesn't match your pattern.

Comment: The line echo "=====$page===="; does well and prints all.. All i need is just to fetch the whole url which has the string 'videoplayback' in it. Once i get the full url then i use file_get_contents of that url

Comment: one thing to watch for, although based on your statements, it doesn't sound like your problem, is that .*? is lazy, and would have no problem matching an empty string. One way to test this theory would be to try changing .*? to .+?, and see if you get a one character match.

Comment: `videoplayback` is not quoted in the example. Is there actually supposed to be a literal `"videoplayback"` in the input? The code looks more like something that tries to match ***the content of an HTML page***, not a URL. The statement *"The string which I'm trying to match is..."* does not appear to be true. Isn't it the ***content*** of the page the URL is pointing to?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to check for the presence of the "videoplayback" in $page, then you could just use:

```
if (preg_match("/.*videoplayback.*/", $page){
    // Use the whole $page URL
}
```

There is isn't any need to trap any internal match components.

You may want to use a tighter pattern, though:

```
$pattern = "/.*youtube\.com\/videoplayback\?.*/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_match('/\"videoplayback\"\:\s\"(.*)\"/iU', $page, $match);
```

If it doesn’t work, also try this:

```
preg_match('/\"videoplayback\"\:\s\"([^\"]*)\"/iU', $page, $match);
```